# Replace string within a array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, arrays, string

```
    NSArray *ArtistNames = [RawData componentsMatchedByRegex:regEx1]; 
    NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"&#39;"];
    ArtistNames = [[ArtistNames componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @"'"];
```

Thats my code at the moment basically i cannot use it as ArtistNames is a array not a string, how would i get past this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're calling your methods in the wrong order. Try breaking it into multiple statements.

```
// The separator should be some string of characters guaranteed to not be in any of the strings in the array.
#define SEPARATOR @"---***---"

NSArray *artistNames = [RawData componentsMatchedByRegex:regEx1]; 
NSString *doNotWant = @"&#39;"
NSString *combinedNames = [artistNames componentsJoinedByString:SEPARATOR];
combinedNames = [combinedNames stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:doNotWant withString:@""];
artistNames = [combinedNames componentsSeparatedByString:SEPARATOR];
```

Comment: SEPARATOR ? sorry im quite new to this object c

Comment: I fixed it thank you i replaced SEPARATOR WITH @"," THANKS THANKS THANKS

Answer (score 1):

Why not just loop over the array and create the second array yourself?